# Why is "but" used in this context by Tolkien?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, literary-english

First chapter of *The Return of the King*:

> Then men fell back before the command of his voice and questioned him no further, though they gazed in wonder at the hobbit that sat before him and at the horse that bore him. For the people of the City used horses very little and they were seldom seen in their streets, save only those ridden by the errand-riders of their lord. And they said: ‘Surely that is one of the great steeds of the King of Rohan? Maybe the Rohirrim will come soon to strengthen us.’ **But Shadowfax walked proudly up the long winding road.**

"But" suggests to me that Shadowfax the horse is doing something contradicting what was just mentioned. Almost as if it's being arrogant. Why didn't the author use "And" instead of "But", or just start the last sentence with "Shadowfax"?

Have I misunderstand the basic meaning of "but"?

Comment: Not up this level of detail for Tolkien, but it seems he is saying that it is a remarkable situation that hobbit is on a horse when only the lord's men are on horseback, and the hobbit isn't one of the lord's men. Wouldn't that make "but" appropriate here?

Answer (score 1):

By Oxford, emphasis mine

1. Used to introduce a phrase or clause *contrasting* with what has already been mentioned.

Contrast isn't a contradiction, but it can be while its possible use is wider, especially in archaic language. Shadowfax moved on with no regard to all that attention she gathered. Similarly there is an archaic use of "but" to start a clause with meaning "without it being the case that".

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/but) gives various meanings such as "yet" or "notwithstanding", which are less than a contradiction. It contrasts more with "For the people of the City used horses very little" than the bit which follows, but "with no regard" or "regardless" is a good gloss.

Comment: @StuartF "notwithstanding" is a good one, but not "yet". "Yet" at beginning of phrase in context of literary language for Tolkien's time (and it's British English!) would have a slightly different meaning, "up until now". It is rarer to be used as "however" and Tolkien would have had that instead. "Regardless" doesn't have same cadence, horse pun not intended.